# Sending large of amounts of data cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I am wanting to create a mashup where large amounts of data need to be sent cross domain. I am thinking about using IFRAMES. My question is...

Will this work??
Does Google use it ??

Does anyone have a concept or some type of psuedo that describes how google does it?

I pretty much need to know how to go about doing it. I am using jquery so if anyone knows of any examples in jquery, that would be great.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "Does Google use it?". Do you mean will such a technique be SEO-friendly? Or that Google have an example of the technique being used?

Answer (score 0):

Google does index iframes, but not as part of the parent page. So if you would search on the iframe content, you wouldn't find hits on the parent page, but only on the iframe's url.

If you can, better use server-side includes. In for example JSP you can use `<jsp:include>` or `<c:import>` for this. ASP has a comparable thing. PHP has `include()` for this. Frames as part of the website are considered bad practice. Better use them for non-HTML content, such as PDF's.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about making a page like:

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <iframe id='a' src='www.domaina.com'></iframe>
      <iframe id='b' src='www.domainb.com'></iframe>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Where the contents of iframe 'a' want to send data to the contents of iframe 'b'?

If so, you can send data between frames using something like the [gadgets.rpc](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/docs/0.7/reference/gadgets.rpc.html) library. You can enlist in the [Shindig](http://incubator.apache.org/shindig/) project to see the source code for this, but basically it encapsulates various methods based on the particular browser that's being used.

You could also think about using a SWF and ActionScript sockets or LocalConnection to send data and relay it out to the containing iframe's javascript.